# How does one easily add posix support to PHP using yum?

Tags: php, posix, package, centos, yum

I am running CentOS 5.2 and using yum to manage packages. I have had little luck installing php-posix but know with almost 100% certitude that it is a real and available package...somewhere. Has anyone had luck installing it?

FWIW, I am using the following:

`sudo yum install -y php-posix`

**Update:** I've realized that this may be an issue with my host (Slicehost) as I do in fact have cli, posix, and pcntl enabled for my PHP version (5.2.9)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try and see if it's in the testing repository.

To see if it's in that repository.

```
yum --disablerepo=\* --enablerepo=c5-testing list available \*php\*
```

And to install it.

```
yum --enablerepo=c5-testing install php-posix
```

Be aware though, that the PHP version it needs may be higher than you currently have.

Comment: Thanks for this, but sadly, c5-testing doesn't have it either. Might have to use the RPM, but man, what a nightmare.

Comment: Yes.  The URL is:
http://dev.centos.org/centos/5/CentOS-Testing.repo

which you can (as root) 

cd /etc/yum.repos.d && wget http://dev.centos.org/centos/5/CentOS-Testing.repo

Comment: For CentOS 6.4 POSIX functions can be added by installing php-process. I was just trying to get phpsh to work with php 5.4 on CentOS 6.4 and this thread lead me to this solution.

Comment: what about the epel-repo? it's plenty of software.

Answer (score 25):

While the question was for centos, notice that for fedora the `php-posix` package is provided by `php-process` [from fedora 11](http://forums.famillecollet.com/viewtopic.php?id=35). I assume this change also will hit centos at some point.

Comment: On RHEL 5: you will have to install package **php53** since only a package **php53-process** exists. On RHEL 6: **php-process** is directly available.

Comment: You can as well use the "Remi Collet" repository http://blog.famillecollet.com/pages/English-site-introduction to get **php-process** for PHP 5.3 (for EL5 or EL6).

Comment: I personally like using the [IUS community repository](http://iuscommunity.org/Home), this repository was created by rackspace guys ans is well maintained with a lot of lamp related packages (php52, php53, mysql50, mysql51, mysql55, etc). As mentioned by @hlovdal, `php-process` will install `php-posix`.

Comment: That is the correct answer. On Amazon Linux, `php-process` and `php54-process` (for PHP 5.4) provide POSIX functions.

Answer (score 1):

This work for me where I have problem with symfony.

http://blog.myee.web.id/warning-the-posix_isatty-is-available-failed-install-and-enable-the-php_posix-extension-used-to-colorized-the-cli-output/

I Hope work for you.
thanks

Comment: Thank you! I had to use `yum install php70u-process` since I have php 7.0 installed.

Answer (score 0):

I am running CentOS 5.3.  The PHP that is included already has the Posix functions built in.  You may or may not have found the [introdctory documentation for the POSIX functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.posix.php) (which indicate that these functions are not available in Windows).  Have you tried using a particular function and it didn't work?

```
    <?php print_r(posix_uname()) ?>
```

in its own file works for me.

Comment: Yes, I'm using CentOS 5.2 (Final) and PHP v5.2.9 with cli, pcntl, and posix enabled - yet none of the posix functions are defined.