# pcntl and posix

Tags: php, mysql, unix, pear

I keep getting the following error

Fatal error: Uncaught System_Daemon_Exception: PHP is compiled without --enable-pcntl directive in

I have used the PEAR Daemon program to create a daemon but I keep getting the error above.

I'm guessing I need the posix and pcntl extensions, but how do I install/enable pcntl and posix for PHP without recompiling PHP?

also I used the yum command but no package was found.

I'm on a CENTOS Linux server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CentOS 5.7 does not ship with those packages.

- Installing php-posix: [How does one easily add posix support to PHP using yum?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1008436/282601)
- Installing php-pcntl: https://serverfault.com/q/158113/75968

pcntl does not seem to be available, so either compile it yourself or use an additional repository, e.g. [EPEL](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL). We used it to get current php versions.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do the same thing, and the only way that worked was compiling the pcntl extension itself -- at least it wasn't recompiling the whole php source.  The method I used I mentioned in my answer at [the serverfault question cweiske linked to](https://serverfault.com/a/383901/34657).

I managed to adapt the instructions there to also work for the posix module, by just performing the same steps with "pcntl" replaced with "posix".